# Difference between Percona XtraDB Cluster and MySQL Cluster

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, percona

How does the newly released Percona XtraDB Cluster compare with MySQL Cluster?

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/01/09/announcement-of-percona-xtradb-cluster-alpha-release/

Answer (score 3):

Simply the Percona XtraDB Cluster is MySQL 5.5 with the Galera replication (synch multimaster) + other patches. That means that you still keep your data in disk + ram cache where MySQL Cluster keeps all data in RAM and saves to disk. In short, if your dataset is bigger than your RAM you need Percona's cluster.

Comment: So to confirm, xtradb cluster will NOT scale writes, just like any other multi-master sync replication mechanism, and one must use mysql ndb cluster to scale writes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by scaling writes but I do see XtraDB Cluster more like a really nice HA solution for me where I don't need that much RAM like with MySQL cluster.

Comment: Note that MySQL Cluster does give you the option of storing your all or a sub-set of your non-indexed columns on disk rather than in memory and so you can scale beyond your available RAM. It's also worth noting that MySQL Cluster allows you to scale out linearly - both reads and writes - and provides very high levels of availability/fault tolerance.